# add to array values

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I geting from mysql data:

```
$starcik_o = mysql_query("select id, mapa, miasto, nazwa_obiektu from oferty where id = 28");
        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($starcik_o, MYSQL_ASSOC)) $punkty[] = $data;
```

And I want to add another table in to this array, I trying to do it like that:

```
foreach ($punkty as $item)
        {
        $deserialized = unserialize($item['mapa']);
        $punkty['long'] = $deserialized['lng'];
        $punkty['lat'] = $deserialized['lat'];
        }
```

But it's not working like I want to, becouse var_dump($punkty); showing me

```
array(3) 
{ 
    [0]=> array(4) 
    { 
    ["id"]=> string(2) "28" 
    ["mapa"]=> string(97) "a:3:{s:3:"lat";s:17:"49.21103723075132";s:3:"lng";s:18:"22.330280542373657";s:4:"zoom";s:2:"17";}" 
    ["miasto"]=> string(5) "Cisna" 
    ["nazwa_obiektu"]=> string(44) "Cisna - noclegi u Mirosławy w Bieszczadach" 
    } 
    ["long"]=> string(18) "22.330280542373657" 
    ["lat"]=> string(17) "49.21103723075132" 
}
```

Comment: Why are you referencing $punkty within your foreach loop? I have never seen this convention before.

Comment: @Matt Sounds name of his cat!

Comment: @ariel Also, this is the obligatory note that `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated. Use PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or Mysqli (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) going forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
foreach ($punkty as $key => $item)
        {
        $deserialized = unserialize($item['mapa']);
        $punkty[$key]['long'] = $deserialized['lng'];
        $punkty[$key]['lat'] = $deserialized['lat'];
        }
```

Comment: `foreach($punkty as &$item)` is shortly

Comment: I agree, it's the way i'd do it too. except i like to suggest solutions that the poster is more likely to have seen or understand. Understanding referencing and when to use them when your new to programming can be difficult, so he's more likely to copy and paste your solution and not actually understand what's going on. However i don't disagree its the better way in most situations

Answer (score 3):

```
    foreach ($punkty as &$item)
    {
        $deserialized = unserialize($item['mapa']);
        $item['long'] = $deserialized['lng'];
        $item['lat'] = $deserialized['lat'];
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to unset($item) after the end of the foreach() loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$starcik_o = mysql_query("select id, mapa, miasto, nazwa_obiektu from oferty where id = 28");
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($starcik_o, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$punkty1[] = $data[' id'];
$punkty2[] = $data['mapa'];
$punkty3[] = $data['miasto'];
$punkty4[] = $data['nazwa_obiektu'];
.....
}
try this code
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is doing what it's being told to do: it's taking the `lat` and `lng` fields from each item and writing it to the `$punkty` array.

I'm under the assumption that you want the `lat` and `lng` fields to be in each individual item though, not the top-level of the array. In that case, change the loop to be:

```
foreach ($punkty as &$item) {   // added the '&' to reference the item
    $deserialized = unserialize($item['mapa']);
    $item['long'] = $deserialized['lng'];   // saving "long" to item
    $item['lat'] = $deserialized['lat'];    // saving "lat" to item
}
```